# How can I dim my computer screen beyond the minimum in Linux / Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, display, brightness

I just read [this terrific question](https://superuser.com/questions/308415/how-can-i-dim-my-computer-screen-beyond-the-minimum) about dimming the screen on Windows. Are there any similar Linux programs which might **allow the user to dim the screen beyond the dimmest hardware setting**?

Like the OP of the original question, I am using a program to enredden the screen at night (in my case, [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/)).

Comment: I can't test it myself (Ubuntu in a VM) but have you tried [gddccontrol](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/lucid/universe/g/gddccontrol/install.html)? (From [DDCControl](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/index.html))

Comment: @Rik: Thanks. The package is not available for my current (Kubuntu 12.10) desktop, I'm trying to build it now from source.