# How do I decrease the brightness of my screen below the minimum on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, display, brightness

The minimum brightness on my desktop monitor is far too bright. I need a way to reduce the brightness of my screen below the minimum. On my Mac, the app [Brightness Slider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/brightness-slider/id456624497?mt=12) worked perfectly for this purpose.

Based on the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/308415/how-can-i-dim-my-computer-screen-beyond-the-minimum), I tried using Dimmer, but it doesn't work properly in Windows 8. Sometimes it just dims the desktop, or the active window, and doesn't dim anything else. The result is a partially bright screen which looks totally weird.

If it matters, I *really* need this kind of app. If there is no such app available, is it possible that I could code it by myself, somehow? :-|

Comment: Why do you need it? Is it a health issue or is it a comfort issue? [f.lux](http://justgetflux.com/) will change the color temp of the screen which reduces the brightness, but also alters the coloration. If you need it to be dimmed but still need perfect colors for photo editing or something, it won't work. For most users it's great.

Comment: I'm using Dimmer + ScreenWhite (for changing color tone to cool during night) on Windows-8.

Comment: The reason I need it is simply because the brightness is too high even at the minimum. As for f.lux, I am already using it and it works great.

Comment: Do you need a way to dim in addition to f.lux or a way to replace f.lux?

Comment: f.lux merely changes the color temperature. I need a way to decrease the brightness, which f.lux does not do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) has a hidden feature which allows you to decrease your screen's brightness below the minimum set by Windows.**

You can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>pgdn</kbd> to decrease brightness and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>pgup</kbd> to increase brightness.

***Note:*** This is not the same as adjusting screen temperature, which f.lux is also able to do.

[image: Dimming screen with f.lux]

Comment: Oh wow, this is amazing! If only your answer came three years earlier. :D