# Increase brightness of external monitor

Tags: laptop, display, brightness

I have an external monitor plugged into my laptop. But compared to my laptop, the brightness levels are very dim. 
In advanced power settings I can't seem to apply brightness levels to the external monitor. 
Any ideas how to configure this?

Monitor is an ASUS VX229.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/308415/how-can-i-dim-my-computer-screen-beyond-the-minimum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to adjust the brightness from your laptop - you'll need to use the physical control buttons on the monitor.

According to [the manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/547343/Asus-Vx229h.html?page=20#manual) you should go Menu -> Color -> Brightness.

Comment: Alright, the brightness on this monitor is abysmal then. Thanks

Comment: Fyi, I was able to get to a satisfactory level of brightness by using Night View mode.