# How can I reduce brightness extremely without change pixel RGB values of screen?

Tags: windows, brightness, pixels, rgb

How can I reduce brightness extremely without change pixel RGB values of screen?

I want to reduce my screen's brightness extremely (like %100 to %5). I want to satisfy this two issues together:

Issue 1- Screen RGB values shouldn't be changed.

Issue 2- Brightness should be changed between 0-100 percent.

---

Windows brightness tool satisfies Issue-1, but not Issue-2.   (f.lux satisfies also)

I tried some third party programs (Dimmer, Monitor Brightness Reducer) to change brighness between 0-100 percent. They satisfy Issue-2 but not Issue-1.

Comment: And what exactly keeps you from just using your monitor's brightness control?

Comment: I'm using laptop, not external monitor.

Comment: I'm not aware of any notebooks without brightness control.

Comment: Yeah, that is my question's answer. You could enlighten me when I asked this question. I searched answer for 5 days and found a solution by myself.

Comment: I only saw it yesterday when you answered it. ;) I'm sure there's a "Fn" key combination to control brightness though, no need to dive into obscure menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. There should be an official control panel of your graphic card that you can change the screen's brightness hardwarely. Control Panel -> Menu related with Colors -> Set color values to lowest.

For Intel: Intel Control Panel-> Display -> Color Enhancements -> Brightness, Contrast, ...
Further, set value to lowest in Windows Brightness Tool to reduce more brightness

---

Example settings for Intel: (Basically, set values to lowest)
Brightness: 0 -> -60
Contrast: 50 -> 40
Gamma: 1.0 -> 0.4
Hue: 0
Saturation: 0 -> -100

And this solution both satisfies:
Issue-1 (Try to take two different screenshots with different settings, Pixels are completely same)
Issue-2 (Can reduce brightness to like %5)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) - they now have a Windows version as well.

I use it on my Mac since.... well, since I own a mac.

Comment: f.lux doesn't reduce brightness extremely (like %100 -> %1). I must satisfy two issues together.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? https://superuser.com/a/310399/441379

(tl;dr It's a portable app called DimScreen, downloadable [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/28/change-display-screen-brightness-with-dimscreen/))

Comment: This program doesnt satisfies Issue-1. You can take two different screenshots with different brightness values and compare them.