# Dim screen below minimum brightness level

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, brightness, f.lux

I have both set my screen brightness to 0% in Windows 10 and activated f.lux at the lowest possible value (2700K), but I still think it's too bright.

Is it possible to further dim the screen or obtain a value lower than 2700K in f.lux?

Comment: Temperature has nothing to do with brightness. Even if in the long run a warmer gamma may tire your eyes slightly less, you are still going to be just as dry/blinded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Is it possible to further dim the screen or obtain a value lower than 2700K in f.lux?

You can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>pgdn</kbd> to decrease brightness and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>pgup</kbd> to increase brightness.

Comment: It's just a black filter not the hardware brittleness

Answer (score 15):

For Windows Intel users:
right click the desktop and go to “Graphics Properties…”. 
There you can reduce brightness for your screen. 
This also works with dual monitors.
[image]

Comment: Since Windows 10 version 21H2, Intel's "Graphic Control Panel" is not included any longer. Instead, Intel's "Graphics Command Center" ¨can be installed manually.

Answer (score 4):

Use an app called dimmer made by Nelson Pires. It can dim your screen farther than Windows will allow.

The link may change
https://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer

Comment: Does it actually save laptop battery or does it just overlays a daker filter on the screen?

Comment: I know it overlays a darker filter on your screen, but I’m not sure if it saves battery life. The filter should theoretically help with the battery because it would put less strain on your monitor to produce light, but again I can’t be sure

Comment: @PeterOLoughlin, my understanding is that standard LCDs (not OLED or other) actually take *more* energy to display a darker color because the LCD has to block out the light being display in the backplane. I'm not pro on this topic, but this is my understanding.

Comment: As of Nov 2023, can't seem to find link to download on the page

Answer (score -1):

Reducing Screen Brightness of Windows 10, 8 PC is not a great issue since many customization settings let decrease or increase it on Windows 8 Laptop or PC. You feel problem when your PC or Laptop screen displays unbearable brightness on the minimum level. This could also happen when you are on your PC is in darkness and you like to reduce screen brightness lower than the minimum. At this juncture, you find no option on your Windows 10, 8 Laptop settings which can lower down further. At this time, you start searching an application or software that makes it possible. For the solution of this issue, Dimmer is a great application. It decreases brightness very easily and saves your eyes.

Comment: Do you have a link to Dimmer?  That's a very generic word.