# Reduce brightness level below 0 level on WIndows 11

Tags: windows-11, brightness

How can I reduce brightness level below 0 level on Windows 11? [Previous thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1086993/dim-screen-below-minimum-brightness-level#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20alt%20%2B%20pgdn,alt%20%2B%20pgup%20to%20increase%20brightness.&text=For%20Windows%20Intel%20users%3A%20right,also%20works%20with%20dual%20monitors.) is about windows 10 and it suggests to use Intel Graphics Setting, which is now Intel Graphics Command Center and does not have an option to reduce brightness. I am on Europe-USA flight right now, no outlets to charge, it is super dark in the plane, and level 0 brightness is way tooo bright.

Comment: I have seen this question before. My own screen is so dim at 0 brightness it is difficult to manage. In other questions it has been an issue with the particular computer. Try an updated video driver. You cannot set below 0.