# Is there a way to edit the windows registry for enabling brightness lower than the current minimum?

Tags: windows-10

I am sensitive to screen lights, I want to know if there is any method of improving the minimum brightness value in Windows 10 to an even lower brightness value by editing the registry.

Comment: Have you looked at the parameters?

Comment: I have done everything i could. Still not  enough. since I am a computer engineering student, I want to know how I can solve my problem using the edition of regisistar approach also @Toto

Comment: The registry is not a repository of tweaking every tiny detail of hardware. You can only change things exposed by drivers using settings that are specifically chosen to be exposed. If you are "sensitive" then you might want to look into anti-glare or privacy filters to apply to your screen https://www.google.com/search?q=anti+glare+filter

Comment: You might also use Windows Dark mode (if not done yet).

Comment: Check out this: https://superuser.com/questions/1086993/dim-screen-below-minimum-brightness-level

Comment: If you do not find a way to do this in software, consider hardware: 1) if proficient in electronics, put a resistor in series with backlight (assuming LCD -- you did not state machine). 2) Put  gray plastic in front of screen, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/s?k=gray+ligh+reducing+plastic+sheet.

Comment: download an app called twinkletray - this places brightness control on your toolbar bottom right - it may have a better range